# i want to fetch the data to text in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, fetch

I want to fetch the username from data and print it in the screen . I make it in local host of the app but I want to print it like .
Welcome (user from data ),
I am sure the data is working and the alert is working but i need to make it text not a alert !
if you can help that will be great

[image: my code]

Comment: Where do you want to display it?  In a Text component?

Comment: Please, share your code as text instead of an image. That said, I would recommend you to use [`state`](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-state.html) to do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have to define the user property in the State object

```
class HomeScreen extends Component{
 
 state = { user: ''}
 
 displayData = async () => {
  
  try{
    let user = await AsyncStorage.getItem("UserEmail");
    this.setState({user:user})
  }catch(error){
    alert(error)
  }
}
 
render(){
  return (
   <View>
     <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.displayData}>
       <Text>Click to display data</Text>
     </TouchableOpacity>
     {this.state.user ?  <Text>Welcome {this.state.user} </Text>: null}
   </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: the alert is working but the text isn't showing up at all